# What are the syntax enabling patterns in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

There are several pattern-features of C# language, i.e. classes need not derive from a specific interface; but rather implement a certain pattern in order to partake in some C# syntax/features.

Let's consider an example:

```
public class MyCollection : IEnumerable
{
    public T Add(T name, T name2, ...) { }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return null; }
}
```

Here, `TYPE` is any type. Basically we have a class that implements `IEnumerable` and has a method named `Add()` with any number of parameters.

This enables the following declaration of a new `MyCollection` instance:

```
new MyCollection{{a1, a2, ...}, {b1, b2, ...} }
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var mc = new MyCollection();
mc.Add(a1, a1, ...);
mc.Add(b1, b2, ...);
```

**Magic!** Meanwhile, recently (I believe during the BUILD event) Anders Hejlsberg let slip that the new `await/async` will be implemented using patterns as well, which lets WinRT get away with returning something other than `Task<T>`.

So my question is twofold,

1. What is the pattern Anders was talking about, or did I misunderstand something? The answer should be somewhere between the type WinRT provides, something to the effect of `IAsyncFoo` and the unpublished specification.
2. Are there any other such patterns (perhaps already existing) in C#?

Comment: You should probably check out Jon Skeet's blog to see how the async stuff works. He disects it in great depth, mainly by showing how you /could/ implement it yourself.

Comment: Not sure if you've read this blog post [Following the pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx), but you might find it interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The draft specification *is* published - you can download it from the [Visual Studio home page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async). The pattern for async is the one given in driis's answer - you can also read my [Eduasync blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx) for more details, with [this post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/05/13/eduasync-part-3-the-shape-of-the-async-method-awaitable-boundary.aspx) being dedicated to the pattern.

Note that this pattern *only* applies to "what you can await". An async method *must* return `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`.

In terms of other patterns in C# beyond the collection initializer you mentioned originally:

- `foreach` can iterate over non-IEnumerable implemenations, so long as the type has a `GetEnumerator` method returning a type which has `MoveNext()` and `Current` members
- [LINQ query expressions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx) resolve to calls to `Select`, `Where`, `GroupBy` etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon, do you think that this is the complete list of such features?

Answer (score 6):

For `async`, it works on the *awaiter pattern*, which I think [is described best here, by Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx):

"*The languages support awaiting any instance that exposes the right method (either instance method or extension method): GetAwaiter.  A GetAwaiter needs to return a type that itself exposes three members:*"

```
bool IsCompleted { get; }
void OnCompleted(Action continuation);
TResult GetResult(); // TResult can also be void
```

As an example of this, in the Async CTP, Task’s GetAwaiter method returns a value of type TaskAwaiter:

```
public struct TaskAwaiter 
{ 
    public bool IsCompleted { get; }
    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation); 
    public void GetResult(); 
}
```

If you want all the details of `async`, start [reading Jon Skeets posts about `async`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx). They go into great detail about the subject.

---

Besides collection initializers, which is pattern based as you mention, another pattern based feature in C# is LINQ: For the LINQ keywords, all that is required is that overload resolution finds an instance or extension method with the correct name and signature. Have a look at [Eric Lipperts article about the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx). Also, `foreach` is pattern based - Eric also describes the details on this pattern in the linked article.

Answer (score 2):

Another pattern you can use is the using keyword.
If you have a class that implements `IDisposable` then you can say:

```
using(Resource myResource = GetResource())
{
}
```

Which translates to something akin to::

```
Resource myResource;
try
{
     myResource = GetResource();
}
finally
{
     var disposable = myResource as IDisposable;
     if(disposable != null) disposable.Dispose()
}
```

While I suppose it is less "magical" than `foreach` or the query operators it is a relatively nice bit of syntax.

Also a bit more in the same vein you can use the `yield return` to automatically implement an iterator for you.

```
public struct SimpleBitVector32 : IEnumerable<bool>
{

    public SimpleBitVector32(uint value)
    {
        this.data = value;
    }

    private uint data; 
    public bool this[int offset]
    {
        get
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (this.data & (1u << offset)) != 0;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            unchecked
            {
                this.data = value ? (this.data | (1u << offset)) : (this.data & ~(1u << offset));
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<bool> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            yield return this[i];
        }
    }


    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1! You are right on the money with the using-statement, magic-wise, although for some reason I don't want to admit it. I think it's because of the interface-makes-it-kinda-less-magic deal :)